# How can i calculate the values in the weather api

Tags: python, openweathermap, weather-api

How can i calculate the response from the `weather api` like:

```
a = x["wind"]["speed"] returns like 3.09 
b = x["wind"]["deg"] return 36
c = x["visibility"] returns 2200
d = x["main"]["sea_level"] returns 1004
e = x["main"]["grnd_level"] returns 979
f = x["sys"]["sunrise"] returns like 1621468669
g = x["sys"]["sunset"] return like 1621517866
```

how can i calculate the time of `f` and `g` | speed of `a` | direction of `b` | visibility of `c` | and level of `d` and `e` in meters

Comment: it is not so clear what you are trying to achieve? Can you provide a link to the documentation of this API.

Comment: What do you have so far?  Have you fetched a result?  What does it look like?

Comment: i meant like it returns the value as shown but like in the sunrise case how can i calculate the time with the returned value

Comment: I recognize those numbers as UNIX timestamps, I have a solution written for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, those integer values are UNIX timestamps. To get the corresponding datetime, do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dateobjf = datetime.fromtimestamp(f+x["timezone"])
dateobjg = datetime.fromtimestamp(g+x["timezone"])
```

**Edit:** `x["timezone"]` added to return time in some given timezone.
**Edit 2:** For code to print out the GMT offset:

```
hrs = abs(x["timezone"])//3600
mins = abs(x["timezone"])//60-hrs*60
if x["timezone"]>0:
    tzinfo = f"GMT +{hrs}:{mins:02d}"
elif x["timezone"]==0:
    tzinfo = "GMT 0:00"
else:
    tzinfo = f"GMT -{hrs}:{mins:02d}"
print(tzinfo)
```

Comment: and how to calculate the wind speed of `a` , direction like north,south of `b`,visibility of `c` and the height of `d` and `e` in meters

Comment: You have to read the API documentation for that, I don't know whatever units `a` is given in, likely m/s, but `b` is an angle given in degrees, `c` looks like it is in metres, so is `d` and `e`. Ultimately, everything else is fine.

Comment: and if i want to format `dateobjf` in the timezone  fetched by `x["timezone"]` then how can i do that? `x["timezone"]` returns something like `19800`

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Also yes, I recognize that timezone to be +5.5h, which is that of India.

Comment: last question if i want to just get the timezone like `gmt +5:30` from x["timezone"] then how can i do it?